# Q: javafx fxml jdbc getting database data to ListView

Tags: java, jdbc, javafx, fxml

I'm making a program using scene builder to create UI, but I got problem how to load a database to ListView at beginning of the program, I just have no clue how to do it. I created method in Controller class, but I can run it only by button or something like this. My program looks like: http://pastebin.com/y9VCAVWF

I would appreciate any help

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please include your code in the question instead of linking to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Controller create a method called initlialize, this method is called after controller is created and all FXML fields are assigned. Then just simply put `loadEvents();` inside it.

```
@FXML
public void initialize() {
    loadEvents();
}
```

Comment: yes, its working. Thank you for help

Comment: Please accept this answer if you find it useful, so the question won't be seen as unsolved and to honor my work. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah sorry, forgot about it